# Is it possible to create a generic React list component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just getting started with React and ES6 and I am trying to DRY up my app a bit. What I'm looking to do is create a component that takes a collection and an attribute of the items in that collection and turn it into a list. For example, if I pass in a group of authors and specify last name, it will create a list of the authors' last names; using the same component I would like to use it elsewhere and pass in a group of songs and list them out by title.

Here's what I have so far:

**ItemList**:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import Item from './Item'

export default class ItemList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    let items

    if(this.props.items.length === 0){
      items = <div>Nothing Found</div>
    } else {
      items = this.props.items.map(item => {
        return(
          <Item item={item} displayAttribute={this.props.displayAttribute}
        )
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="item-index">
        <div className="list-group">{items}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Item:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

export default class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-group-item" data-index={this.props.item.id}>
        <div className="item-attribute">
          *This is where I want to print the item's display attribute*
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in the app, I would like to be able to call something like the following:

```
<ItemList items={this.state.authors} displayAttribute="last_name" />
```

or

```
<ItemList items={this.state.songs} displayAttribute="title" />
```

and the component would create a list using the specified attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this should do (in your item list):

```
<div className="item-attribute">
   {this.props.item[this.props.displayAttribute]}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me there. I was over-complicating.